# A connection failed but has been re-established. The host name or IP address is "*.*.*.*" and the service name or port number is ***

Tags: java, spring, db2, spring-jdbc, c3p0

Getting the error while doing the update query in DB2 batch update.

exception :

```
org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [UPDATE DBO.STG_BILLPAY_INV_BT SET INV_SENT_FLG = ?, MDY_TS = ?, MDY_USR = ? WHERE INV_PDF_NM = ?]; [jcc][t4][2027][11212][3.53.70] A connection failed but has been re-established. The host name or IP address is "10.1.1.1" and the service name or port number is 446.
Special registers may or may not be re-attempted (Reason code = 2). ERRORCODE=-4498, SQLSTATE=08506; nested exception is com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ClientRerouteException: [jcc][t4][2027][11212][3.53.70] A connection failed but has been re-established. The host name or IP address is "10.1.1.1" and the service name or port number is 446.
Special registers may or may not be re-attempted (Reason code = 2). ERRORCODE=-4498, SQLSTATE=08506
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:105)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:82)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:82)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:655)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:668)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:956)
    at com.comdata.batch.billtrust.dao.jdbc.ThinBillFileDaoJdbc.updateThinBillFile(ThinBillFileDaoJdbc.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy12.updateThinBillFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.comdata.batch.billtrust.service.impl.ThinBillFileServiceImpl.getStagingThinBillData(ThinBillFileServiceImpl.java:297)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy15.getStagingThinBillData(Unknown Source)
    at com.comdata.batch.billtrust.MainBatch.executeThinBilFileProcess(MainBatch.java:37)
    at com.comdata.batch.billtrust.MainBatch.main(MainBatch.java:51)
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ClientRerouteException: [jcc][t4][2027][11212][3.53.70] A connection failed but has been re-established. The host name or IP address is "10.1.1.1" and the service name or port number is 446.
Special registers may or may not be re-attempted (Reason code = 2). ERRORCODE=-4498, SQLSTATE=08506
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.bd.a(bd.java:304)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.bd.a(bd.java:356)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.a(a.java:380)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.I(a.java:811)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.a.a(a.java:716)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.T(bb.java:1240)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.bb.A(bb.java:610)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.o(db.java:771)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.g(db.java:141)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.db.a(db.java:38)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.t.a(t.java:32)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.sb.h(sb.java:141)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.fm.bb(fm.java:1923)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.gm.dc(gm.java:2551)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.gm.q(gm.java:2678)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.gm.Ub(gm.java:1966)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.gm.addBatch(gm.java:1917)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.addBatch(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:131)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:970)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:956)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:639)
    ... 32 more
```

XML Configuration :
Spring JDBC template with c3p0 configuration.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="user" value="${billtrust.db.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${billtrust.db.password}" />
        <property name="driverClass" value="${billtrust.db.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${billtrust.db.url}" />
        <property name="initialPoolSize" value="1" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="1" />
        <property name="acquireIncrement" value="1" />
        <property name="maxIdleTimeExcessConnections" value="300" />
        <!-- maxConnectionAge: connection lifetime seconds -->
        <property name="maxConnectionAge" value="7200" />
        <!-- acquireRetryAttempts is how many times connect is retried before giving 
            up, 0 = infinite, should be 1 in unit tests -->
        <property name="acquireRetryAttempts" value="30" />
        <!-- acquireRetryDelay is how many wait time in ms between reconnect attempts -->
        <property name="acquireRetryDelay" value="1000" />
        <!-- checkoutTimeout: nbr of millis request will wait for a pooled connection 
            when maxed out -->
        <property name="checkoutTimeout" value="60000" />
    </bean>
```

Sample Code :
batch update using jdbc template of BatchPreparedStatementSetter.
    BatchPreparedStatementSetter preparedStatementSetter = new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

```
            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                java.sql.Timestamp ourJavaTimestampObject = new java.sql.Timestamp(calendar.getTime().getTime());
                ps.setString(1, option);
                ps.setTimestamp(2, ourJavaTimestampObject);
                ps.setString(3, "JAVA");
                ps.setString(4, thinBillFileUpdate.get(i));
            }

            @Override
            public int getBatchSize() {
                return thinBillFileUpdate.size();
            }

        };

int[] batchUpdate = this.getJdbcTemplate().batchUpdate(updateThinBillStagingTable, preparedStatementSetter);


Should get update the Database(DB2) successfully.
```

Comment: Do you get the error every time you issue such a batch update, or intermittently?

Answer (score 0):

Key error message would be:

---

Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.**ClientRerouteException**: [jcc][t4][2027][11212][3.53.70] A connection failed but has been re-established. The host name or IP address is "10.1.1.1" and the service name or port number is 446.
Special registers may or may not be re-attempted (Reason code = 2). **ERRORCODE=-4498**, SQLSTATE=08506

---

Here is the explanation about -4498:

**Error codes issued by the IBM Data Server Driver for JDBC and SQLJ**
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_rjvjcsqc.html
snipped

---

-4498
    Message text: A connection failed but has been re-established. Special register settings have been replayed if necessary. Host name or IP address of the connection: host-name. Service name or port number of the connection: service-name. Reason code: reason-code. Failure code: failure-code. Error code: error-code.

    Explanation: The connection has been reestablished. In some cases, the network connection or transport to the server is not established until the next use. After the connection is reestablished, all session resources are set to their initial default values. The application is rolled back to the previous commit point. The reason code indicates which special register values are applied to the new connection. Possible values for the reason code are:

---

Here is one of good references for -4498 and ClientRerouteException:

**Configuring DB2 HADR seamless failover for MobileFirst Server and Application Center data sources**
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/install_config/c_config_db2_hadr_seamless_failover.html

snipped

---

By default with DB2 HADR, when the DB2 JDBC driver performs a client reroute after detecting that a database failed over during the first attempt to reuse an existing connection, the driver triggers com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.**ClientRerouteException**, with **ERRORCODE=-4498** and SQLSTATE=08506.

---

So it may be logged at Db2 HADR environment when a database failed over.

Hope this helps.